# How to Login to ISP Login Page by a Shell Scipt?

Tags: command-line, networking, scripts, login

I have a ISP that randomly logs me out and my connection gets lost.So i want to write a script that automatically logs me in without user interaction when logged out (which i can test using a ping exit status).But the problem is i don't know anything about web programming.I tried curl but cant figure stuff out.Tried elinks but it does not work as a script or as a cronjob without user interaction

what i have tried so far

```
cat ~/bin/elink 
elinks -auto-submit http://192.168.1.2:9088/WISHN/Login.jsp
```

**by running this command it auto logs me in (by editing ~/.elinks/elinks.conf)**

but it just stays there untill user interacts and exits the app but pressing **"q"**

thats why this script does not work

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
  do
    . ~/bin/elink
    slleep 3
    pkill-9 elinks
    sleep 5
done
```

the next command does not run untill elinks exits

```
timeout 1m elinks -auto-submit http://192.168.1.2:9088/WISHN/Login.jsp
```

this does not works too nothing happens

I tried these with curl but as usual does not work

```
curl -d "Username=someuser&Password=shhhitsasecret" -s http://192.168.1.2:9088/WISHN/loginUI.do2
```

and this

```
curl -d "Username=someuser&Password=shhhitsasecret" -s http://192.168.1.2:9088/WISHN/Login.jsp
```

i found the **loginUI.do**2 in the   **action** section of the source but it fails too

im pretty much empty of ideas any help will be very apreciated

and here is the source of the page i have deleted some parts that could result in privacy violation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">





<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<title>somewebsite</title>

<link href="templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/style_pop.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

<!--
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function clearText(field)
{
    if (field.defaultValue == field.value) field.value = '';
    else if (field.value == '') field.value = field.defaultValue;
}
</script>-->
<script language="JavaScript">
function newCookie(Username,value,days) {
     var days = 30;   // the number at the left reflects the number of days for the cookie to last
                     // modify it according to your needs
     if (days) {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
       var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString(); }
       else var expires = "";
       document.cookie = Username+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; }

    function readCookie(Username) {
       var nameSG = Username + "=";
       var nuller = '';
      if (document.cookie.indexOf(nameSG) == -1)
        return nuller;

       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameSG) == 0) return c.substring(nameSG.length,c.length); }
        return null; }

    function eraseCookie(Username) {
      newCookie(Username,"",1); }

    function toMem(a) {
        newCookie('theName', document.login.Username.value);     // add a new cookie as shown at left for every
        newCookie('theEmail', document.login.Password.value);   // field you wish to have the script remember
    }

    function delMem(a) {
      eraseCookie('theName');   // make sure to add the eraseCookie function for every field
      eraseCookie('theEmail');

       document.login.Username.value = '';   // add a line for every field
       document.login.Password.value = ''; }


    function remCookie() {
    document.login.Username.value = readCookie("theName");
    document.login.Password.value = readCookie("theEmail");
    }


    function addLoadEvent(func) {
      var oldonload = window.onload;
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
      } else {
        window.onload = function() {
          if (oldonload) {
            oldonload();
          }
          func();
        }
      }
    }

    addLoadEvent(function() {
      remCookie();
    });
function correctPNG() // correctly handle PNG transparency in Win IE 5.5 & 6.
{
   var arVersion = navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")
   var version = parseFloat(arVersion[1])
   if ((version >= 5.5) && (document.body.filters)) 
   {
      for(var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++)
      {
         var img = document.images[i]
         var imgName = img.src.toUpperCase()
         if (imgName.substring(imgName.length-3, imgName.length) == "PNG")
         {
            var imgID = (img.id) ? "id='" + img.id + "' " : ""
            var imgClass = (img.className) ? "class='" + img.className + "' " : ""
            var imgTitle = (img.title) ? "title='" + img.title + "' " : "title='" + img.alt + "' "
            var imgStyle = "display:inline-block;" + img.style.cssText 
            if (img.align == "left") imgStyle = "float:left;" + imgStyle
            if (img.align == "right") imgStyle = "float:right;" + imgStyle
            if (img.parentElement.href) imgStyle = "cursor:hand;" + imgStyle
            var strNewHTML = "<span " + imgID + imgClass + imgTitle
            + " style=\"" + "width:" + img.width + "px; height:" + img.height + "px;" + imgStyle + ";"
            + "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader"
            + "(src=\'" + img.src + "\', sizingMethod='scale');\"></span>" 
            img.outerHTML = strNewHTML
            i = i-1
         }
      }
   }    
}

/* ------- Trim ------- */

function trim(str) {
    return ltrim(rtrim(str));
}

function ltrim(str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp("^[\\s]+", "g"), "");
}

function rtrim(str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp("[\\s]+$", "g"), "");
}
/* ------- End of Trim ------- */
function validateForm(){
    var input=true;
    document.login.Username.value = trim(document.login.Username.value);
        if(document.login.Username.value.length==0){
            alert("User Name is required.");
            document.login.Username.focus();
            input=false;
            return false;
    }
    if(document.login.Password.value.length==0){
        alert("Password is required.");
            document.login.Password.focus();
            input=false;
            return false;
    }
    var uname = "?"+document.login.Username.value+"+/@";
    var pwd = "?"+document.login.Password.value+"+/@";      
    document.login.LoginName.value=encodeURIComponent(uname); 
    document.login.LoginPassword.value=encodeURIComponent(pwd);
    if (input==true&&document.login.checker.checked) 
        toMem(this);
}
window.attachEvent("onload", correctPNG);
</script>
</head>


         <!--Main Container Starts here-->




        <form name="login" method="post" action="loginUI.do2" onSubmit="if (this.checker.checked) toMem(this)" id="login-form">





<body>
<div id="templatemo_wrapper">
    <div id="templatemo_menu">
<marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="slide" direction="left" height="20" width="100%" style="color:#00162b"><p>&nbsp; Your Default Password is <strong style="color:#FFFFFF">wnpl123</strong> for first time login only. Please change your password after first login.</p></marquee>
    </div> <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->

    <div id="templatemo_header_bar">

            <div id="header"><!--<div class="right"></div>-->

                <h1><a href="#">
                    <img src="images/templatemo_logo.png" alt="Site Title" width="254" />
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                </a></h1>
      </div>

            <div  style=" font-size:22px; color:#000; margin-top:50px; float:right; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; left: 878px; top: 0px; width: 285px;">
              Toll Free : 1800 419 4244            </div>

    </div> <!-- end of templatemo_header_bar -->

    <div class="cleaner"></div>

    <div id="sidebar"><div class="sidebar_top"></div><div class="sidebar_bottom"></div>

        <div class="sidebar_section">

            <h2>Login Form</h2>
            <div style="color:#FFFF00; font-size:12px; margin-top:45px; margin-bottom:10px;"><b>

        </b></div>


                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="Username" size="20" class="input_field" />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" value="" name="Password" class="input_field" title="password" />
                <input  type="hidden" name="LoginName" />
                <input  type="hidden" name="LoginPassword" />
               <label for="checkbox"><br><input type="checkbox" name="checker" id="checker" /> Remember Me</label>
            <br />


 <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit_btn" onClick="return validateForm()" />



        </div>





    </div> <!-- end of sidebar -->

    <div id="templatmeo_content">

        <div id="latest_product_gallery">


   <img src="images/bannerr.png" />
   <a href="index1.html" target="_blank"> <div class="intro-texttt" align="right"></div>
   </a>


        </div> <!-- end of latest_content_gallery -->



  </div>
    Z<!-- end of templatmeo_content -->


</div> <!-- end of templatemo_wrapper -->

<!--<div class="popupbox3" id="popuprel3">
<div id="intabdiv3" align="left">
<table border="0"  align="left">
<tr height="16px"><td></td></tr>
<tr height="16px"><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><h2> Steps to Install:-</h2> </td><tr>
<tr><td><Font color="#000000"><strong>1.</strong> <a href="http://172.18.1.60/gamestore/UrbanTerror.rar" style="color:#0000CC">Download</a> UrbanTerror -> Extract UrbanTerror.rar-></font></td></tr><tr><td><Font color="#000000" > Install UrbanTerror.exe</font></td></tr><tr height="14px"><td></td></tr>

<tr><td><Font color="#000000">
<strong> 2.</strong><b>Play :</b><i>Online </i>|<b>Source :</b><i>Favorites </i>| <b> Type : </b><i>On/All</i></font> </td></tr>
<tr><td><Font color="#000000" >
<b>Create Favourite Name : </b><i>WISH-UT </i></font></td></tr>
<tr><td><Font color="#000000" >
<b> IP Address :</b><i>172.18.1.60  |</i>
<b> Guides: </b><i>On/All</i></font></td></tr>
<tr><td><Font color="#000000">
<b>OK & CONNECT</b></font></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

-->


<div id="templatemo_footer_wrapper">

    <div id="templatemo_footer">


        Copyright &copy; 2099 <a href="#">somewebsite</a> | 
        Designed by <a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Wish Net</a>       

    </div> <!-- end of footer -->

</div> <!-- end of footer_wrapper -->
<!--<div id="fade"></div>-->
<!--</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As no one was answering i figured out a way quite basic but does the job .Because i can't figure out curl i figured out a way with elinks by making a script and sourcing it (not making it executable,because it executes the elinks command in a behind the scene shell and it dosent work.

```
 #!/bin/bash



arg1="set document.browse.forms.show_formhist = 1"
arg2="set document.browse.forms.confirm_submit = 0"
count=0
terminal=`tty`

dpkg -s zenity > /dev/null 2>&1

if ! [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then 
      echo "\033[1mzenity is not installed do you want to install y/n \033[0m\c: "

       read choice
        if [ "$choice" = "y" -o "$choice" = "Y" ]

          then      
               sudo apt-get install zenity

          else
                 echo "OK Sorry For Asking Jeez"
                 sleep 3     
                 exit 100
        fi

        if ! [ $? -eq 0 ]
          then
             echo "something went wrong with apt-get so exiting byebye"
             sleep 3
             exit 200
        fi
fi

dpkg -s elinks > /dev/null 2>&1

if ! [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then 
      echo "elinks is not installed you will be prompted for installation in a sec"
        sleep 3
       zenity --question --title="Query" --text="Would you Like to Install Elinks ?"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
            then
               sudo apt-get install elinks
            else
                 zenity --error --title="Hmmmmm" --text="OK Sorry For Asking Jeez"
                exit 100
        fi

        if ! [ $? -eq 0 ]
          then
             echo "something went wrong with apt-get so exiting byebye"
             sleep 3
             exit 200
        fi
fi

zenity --question --title="Query" --text="Do you wanna login to isp page now using elinks to save password if you havent already ?"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]

  then

zenity --info --title="Soooooo" --text="elink will open enter username and password save them so we can do autologin later elink will autoexit in 20 seconds so hurry up"

timeout 20s elinks http://192.168.1.2:9088/WISHN/Login.jsp

 fi

newf () { 

while true

do

echo -e "\033[42m Script For Wishnet AutoLogin By Shantanu Running......\033[0m"

sleep 10m

timeout 3s wget -O /dev/null http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test > /dev/null 2>&1

condition=$?

result=8

case $condition in

$result)

echo "were logged back in"

timeout 5s elinks -auto-submit http://192.168.1.2:9088/WISHN/Login.jsp

;;

*)

echo "nothing is wrong"

;;

esac

done

}

if ! [ -e ~/.elinks/elinks.conf ]

    then
      touch ~/.elinks/elinks.conf

    fi

exec < ~/.elinks/elinks.conf

while read -r line

do
  if [ "$arg1" = "$line" -o "$arg2" = "$line" ]
    then   
       let count+=1
  fi
done

exec < "$terminal"

if [ $count -eq 2 ]

  then
    newf
else
    echo $arg1 > ~/.elinks/elinks.conf

    echo $arg2 >> ~/.elinks/elinks.conf

    newf
fi
```

Comment: You could try Python and Selenium.